# Can you normalize data with embedded sections in excel?

Tags: excel

I was provided with some data in excel that I'm trying to transform to make it filterable.  The data is in a specific order and looks like this:

```
Group ID    RowType     Name
1           Section     Name1
1           Row         AAA
1           Row         BBB
1           Row         CCC
1           Section     Name2
1           Row         DDD
1           Row         EEE
2           Section     ...
```

I want to take the name of the Row Type "Section" and transform it into a constant in it's own column.  The final product would look like:

```
Group ID    Section     RowType     Name
1           Name1       Row         AAA
1           Name1       Row         BBB
1           Name1       Row         CCC
1           Name2       Row         DDD
1           Name2       Row         EEE
2           ...
```

I feel like this has probably be done but I haven't been able to put together the right terms to search...  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes it can be done and if you have put together **any** code then you should include it.

Comment: Fair enough - I was just thinking there was a relatively easy solution right within excel that would work.